# Python : Print some lines of a file in terms of the number of lines

Tags: python

here is my problem:
I have many files with each of them containing various numbers of lines, from 2 to 437 lines.

What I would like is to print the first line if the file has less than 10 lines, the first and the tenth if the file has between 10 and 19, the first, the tenth and the twentieth if the file has between 20 and 29 lines, and so on.

For example, let's say that one of the files has 98 lines. Then I would like to print the 1st, 10th, 20th, 30th, 40th, 50th, 60th, 70th, 80th and 90th lines of the file.

Thank you

EDIT:

Here is the code I have so far:

```
line_num=0

for line_num, l in enumerate(file1, 1):
    pass
line_num+1


if line_num<10:
    print(linecache.getline(file1, 1)

if 10<=line_num<20:
    print(linecache.getline(file1, 1)
    print(linecache.getline(file1, 10)
```

I don't see myself copy/paste 40 times the 'if' statement for each case.

Comment: 1) Man it is hard to dechiper what you wrote, please add a desired input and output example, do you not want to print the lines (2-9) in your example? 2) What code have you tried? You ask a coding question but fail to show what you have tried. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: `I don't see myself copy/paste 40 times the 'if' statement for each case.`- yes, you shouldn't. Use loops instead.

Comment: Hint: iterate over the file using `enumerate`

Comment: "I don't see myself copy/paste 40 times the 'if' statement for each case." - then use loop and do your math. Print 1st, skip to 10th lines and print, skip to 20th and print... Hint: between 10th and 20th is the same number of lines than between 20th and 30th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to print the first line, and then every 10th line afterwards so long as the file is long enough to do that. Here's how you'd do that:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as infile:
    file_lines = infile.readlines()
    for line in file_lines[::10]:
        print(line)
```

This is list slicing - start at the beginning of the list, continue until the end of the list, and step by 10 elements each time. You'll end up getting a list of elements `0`, `10`, `20`, ..., and printing just those.

Comment: You would be better off using `range(0, len(infile), 10)` because `splicing` creates a whole new list (temporarily in memory in this type of use-case).  I'll be it, it would be a 10th the size of the original because it has a step of 10 but if the list is big enough that is still a lot of memory.

Comment: Thank you both, that's exactly what I wanted